# How can I video record a div in JS

Tags: javascript, video

I have an animation happening in a div element. I want to record the div element in a given frame rate and resolution and export it as a file. How can do it in JS. I already searched quite a bit but all JS video recording samples I found are about WebRTC. But I do not want to record a webrtc stream. I just want to record a div element in 1280x720 sizes with 60fps.

Answer (score 6):

AFAIK there are no ways of recording real time video from regular div elements. You can however fairly easily record media elements, such as `canvas`, `video` and `audio` elements. If you want to record an arbitrary animation, your best bet is probably to draw the animation to a canvas element and record it from there.

The approach looks like this:

- Create a canvas(/video/audio)-element, draw your animations in realtime to the canvas
- Use the method `HTMLCanvasElement.captureStream(framerate)` to initiate capturing the stream and getting the handler to the stream instance (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/captureStream)
- Use the MediaStream Recording API to start recording on the stream instance (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API)
- When finished recording, you can export the result to a media-download link, upload the data blob to a server, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use timecut JS lib to record. It uses puppeteer to take high quality screenshots and create a video of it.  It can also record a specific div element and very high frame rate.

https://github.com/tungs/timecut